# Python module that assesses likelihood that text is gibberish?

Tags: python, nlp

I'd like to check whether words or paragraphs of text are likely to contain valid "words," without checking individual words against a dictionary. Basically, the use case is to test whether a website's user entered a bunch of gibberish as input.

For my purposes, it would be enough to have a plugin that checks that there's no inordinate number of sequential consonants or vowels, or that the "words" contain reasonable syllable combinations. For example, it would be fine if the plugin acts in the following ways in the following cases:

- Something like ["Lekreauclig" or "Prostrebaughi"](http://www.dwheeler.com/totro.html) could be treated as a word, since the letter combos look reasonable enough.
- Something like "twumczsarn" or "aeigou" would be flagged as "probably not a word", since it has strange sequential consonant or vowel combos.
- "mqbadtxjtc" would be flagged as "not a word"

I'm indifferent to the mechanism by which the module works (perhaps it could be some machine learning-based module that was pre-trained on an english language dictionary), as long as the module is small (so nltk is not an option), suitable for use in a web application, and pre-trained and ready to use, if it works by a method which necessitates training. If it can check paragraphs of text to detect the likelihood that its constituent strings contain gibberish, and give an overall measure of the paragraph's validity, rather than only assessing individual words, even better. Can anyone recommend some modules that are well-suited for this purpose?

Comment: I'd suggest that grabbing 5 words at random, and validating them against a word list would be a pretty good first pass, and wouldn't require all that much work.

Comment: If aeigou is probably not a word, what about aeon and beauty?

Comment: @AustinHastings - so you're suggesting using a "check against a dictionary" approach? I excluded that possibility in the question, given that the approach I use would have to be suitable for a web application (i.e. keeping a dictionary in memory, takes up too much memory; reading a dict each time you need to perform this function, would consume inordinate resources).

Comment: @Boa `/usr/share/dict/american-english` contains 100 000 words and is 1 MB. Memory is not a problem here.

Comment: @AlexHall - I assume that if there's a module roughly matching the criteria I listed above, it has probably addressed the "aeon" and "beauty" scenarios, either incidentally (i.e. by virtue of the mechanism by which it works), or specifically. I intentionally left out the specifics of how the module should work, and would prefer to focus on the use case: namely, assessing a probability to whether user-generated text is likely to be considered "gibberish" by the intuitive criteria that you or I would probably apply.

Comment: @AlexHall - I'd consider 1 MB problematic. Consider that if it's stored in memory, it would be stored over multiple application instances on the server. It's also time-consuming to search it, especially if you're going through paragraphs of text.

Comment: 1 MB is very small compared to the other things you will be storing. Using a set will give you constant time searches.

Comment: May I suggest to change *likelihood* but some other term? It's [misleading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function)... Perhaps something like *odds* or *feasibility*?

Comment: How about getting percentage of vowels, consonants, and changes through them, and train a classificator (SVM, ANN, KNN) offline over an english dictionary? The end (trained) module is quite light in the end.

Comment: @Luis - I was using "likelihood" in the colloquial sense. It's indeed a vague (not necessarily misleading) term, and in this case, intentionally so. Regarding using some ML classifier algorithm - sure, that's feasible, but again, I was looking for some ready-to-use solution that bypassed the training step, if one is available.

Comment: @AlexHall - I tried reading [this dictionary (about 1 MB)](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106l/assignments/dictionary.txt) into a set. `sys.getsizeof()` suggests that the size of the set object is a bit over 4 MB. Task manager, on the other hand, shows python taking up over 10 MB of memory more than it did before the dictionary was read into a set. Storing that dictionary file in a list would take less space (a bit more than the size of the file), but you'd lose the constant-time search.

Answer (score 2):

This should be a good start: [gibberishclassifier.py](https://github.com/ProgramFOX/GibberishClassifier-Python/blob/master/gibberishclassifier.py)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a simple solution, but have you thought about using a language detection tool, based on n-grams of characters?

If the input is detected as english with high probability, then it should be fine, and contains no gibberish. If it's classified has any other language or english with low confidence than you could assume it's gibberish

This solution, of course, is only valid if you are always expecting English text as an input.

Some out-of-the-box, ready to use implementations of language detection based on n-grams of characters:

[langid](https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py)

[langdetect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/langdetect)

Comment: Probabilistic Language Model works.

Logic

word is made up of sequence of characters, and if 2 characters come together more frequently and if we sum up all frequency of 2 contiguous characters coming together in word, and sum cross threshold limit (being an english word), it is said to proper english word. In brief, this logic is famous by Markov chains.

Link

For Mathematics of Gibberish and better understanding, refer to video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l15C8UJu17s . Thanks !!